# Showing items as in a Carousel

Tags: html, erb

Is there a better way to implement my carousel in less lines?

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
      <% if index == 0 %>
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if index == 1 %>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if index == 2 %>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if index == 3 %>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if index == 4 %>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if index == 5 %>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of unnecessary code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
      <% if index.zero? %>
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% else %>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= photo.image_url(:large) %>" alt="<%= photo.title %>">
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Move stuff to helpers:

```
module PhotoHelpers
  def slider_image(photo)
    image_tag photo.image_url(:large), alt: photo.title
  end
end

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
      <% if index.zero? %>
        <div class="item active">
          <%= slider_image photo %>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>TITLE</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= slider_image photo %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with @NARKOZ's excellent answer, consder converting your template to [haml](http://haml.info/):

```
#myCarousel.carousel.slide
  .carousel-inner
    - @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index|
      - if index.zero?
        .item.active
          %img{:alt => photo.title, :src => photo.image_url(:large)}/
          .container
            .carousel-caption
              %h1 TITLE
      - else
        .item
          %img{:alt => photo.title, :src => photo.image_url(:large)}/
```

All you have to do is name your template *.haml* instead of *.erb*, and include the haml gem in your Gemfile.

The haml gem comes with a conversion script, *html2haml*, which will convert your *erb* to *haml*.